# SSRS expression equivalent to case statement in sql

Tags: reporting-services

I have a simple employee table where a column is departname, and i am trying to add a derived column named 'Location', based on the following sql expression,Can you please help me how to write the below code as an ssrs expression?.
I tried with iif , but no progress

case when departname='Research' then 'Boston'

case when departname='Sales then 'Saint Louis'

case when departname='IT' then 'Newjersey'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `iif` (although you would need to nest a second `iif` inside the expression, as you have three options), but `switch` would probably be more suitable - something like:

```
=Switch(Fields!departname.Value = "Research","Boston",
        Fields!departname.Value = "Sales","Saint Louis",
        Fields!departname.Value = "IT","Newjersey")
```

(Note the use of double quotes rather than single quotes.)

Alternatively, you could add your SQL Case expression to your query as another column.

Comment: @Deepak: Glad I could help.