# Simple Sum expression for more than one field - SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I've got a table in Visual Studio with only two columns: Account Name and Amount.

There are thousands of records but only a handful of Account names.  I have succeeded in running a "summary" report by grouping the data by Account Name and adding in the simple expression below to the data cell in the table.

```
=sum(Fields!Amount.Value)
```

Next, I'd like to consolidate some of the groupings further.

For example, the R&M category is comprised of 3 different account names.

R&M = R&M, Turnover Exp, and Security

Out of the 12 account names, I'm trying to figure out how to isolate and consolidate 3 of them:

```
=sum(Fields!Amount.Value) where 'Account_Name' like 'R&M' or where 'account_name' like 'Turnover Exp' or where 'Account_Name' like Security
```

As you can tell, I'm new at this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use a case statement then group by that case statement

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Marshall.  I have seen the Case statement in some of my reading, but haven't used it yet.  Looks like now is a good time to get familiar with it.

Comment: if you are using SSRS then afaik case statements are not supported.  Have a look at `switch` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008026/ssrs-expression-equivalent-to-case-statement-in-sql

Comment: Also, this is very similar to the other question you asked.  Try not to create additional questions unless the distinction between them is clear, or they may be closed as duplicate questions.